# Why Lucene query not working for other field like StringField type

Tags: java, lucene

for a requirement, I have to store information for many to many relationship.
For each zip code there are N courseIds, for each course code, there are N zip codes.
I am storing information in **Lucene** **version 6.4** like this.

```
private static void updateDoc(IndexWriter w, String id, String zipCode, String courseId) throws IOException {
        Term term = new Term("id", id);
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new StringField("id", id, Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new StringField("zipCode", zipCode, Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new StringField("courseName", courseId, Field.Store.YES));
        w.updateDocument(term, doc);

    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File dataDir = new File("E:/local/data/");
        IndexWriter indexWriter = getIndexWriter(dataDir);

        //Zip Code
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            String zipCode = String.format("%05d", i);

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

                String courseCode = "Course" + String.format("%03d", j);
                String id = getID();
                System.out.println(zipCode + "<---->" + courseCode);
                updateDoc(indexWriter, id, zipCode, courseCode);
            }
        }

        try {
            indexWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

But the problem is while searching, I do not get the hits for Course Ids where I get for zip code.

For the below code , I get the proper result.

```
     String queryStr = "00003";//For zip code only
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
            Query q = new QueryParser("zipCode", analyzer).parse(queryStr);
            System.out.println(q.toString());

            IndexSearcher searcher = getIndexSearcher();
            TopDocs docs = searcher.search(q, 10);
            System.out.println("Total :::" + docs.totalHits);
            ScoreDoc[] hits = docs.scoreDocs;
            System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
            for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; ++i) {
                int docId = hits[i].doc;
                Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
                System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + "---" + d.get("id") + " " + d.get("zipCode") + "\t" + d.get("courseName"));
            }
```

But for the below code, I do not get the result, Ideally it should provide the result. I am trying to retrieve the result for course code in the similar fashion which I have done for zip code.

```
    String queryStr = "Course005";//For course code only
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
            Query q = new QueryParser("courseName", analyzer).parse(queryStr);

            System.out.println(q.toString());

            IndexSearcher searcher = getIndexSearcher();
            TopDocs docs = searcher.search(q, 10);
            System.out.println("Total :::" + docs.totalHits);
            ScoreDoc[] hits = docs.scoreDocs;
            System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
            for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; ++i) {
                int docId = hits[i].doc;
                Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
                System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + "---" + d.get("id") + " " + d.get("zipCode") + "\t" + d.get("courseName"));
            }
```

If you look into the above two code snippets, both are same but the field names are different.

Please help me to understand and also let me know why it is not working.
Please help how to achieve the result by passing only query string and the field name.

Comment: QueryParser does analysis, StringField doesn't. Try a [TermQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermQuery.html).

Comment: I know TermQuery may work, then why is my first program working, it means "Query q = new QueryParser("zipCode", analyzer).parse(queryStr);" works correctly. I want to know where am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Typical analysis won't have any impact on a zip code. It will lowercase text, though. [See here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html) for some explanation on how analysis works.